# apache poi write to temp file instead real file

Tags: java, apache-poi

i have a excel file which serve as a template and will be writted and downloaded by several users

I am using apache poi for doing this
The problem is when one user fill the excel (using a gui client) it will be writted directly to the template but as a template it should stay unmodified otherwise next user will have previous user changes ....

The best solution i think is to write to a temp files which will be deleted at user's action exit

Thank you very much

```
        File excelFile = openTemplate(); 
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(excelFile ,PackageAccess.READ_WRITE); 
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
        book.setWorkbookType(XSSFWorkbookType.XLSX);
        book.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

        // excel treatments ( sheet , styles etc..)

        FileOutputStream out = 
                new FileOutputStream(TempFile.createTempFile("Export" , ".xlsx"));
        book.write(out);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bos.writeTo(out);
        bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        bos.close();
        book.close();
        return bytes;
```

Comment: You should call `bos.close()` before `bos.toByteArray()`.

Comment: You appear to be writing to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of the `File` you created as a temp file - what happens when you change the code to actually write to your temp file?

Comment: @beckyang thanks , code updated

Comment: @Gagravarr . Thank you very much ,  you are right indeed but how can i write to the temp file because write method need to get applied on the worbook object ?

Comment: Why not just clone the workbox to a new instance?

Comment: or copy the sheets from the workbook to a new workbook instance.

Comment: @Javant . Thank you for your help but i tried with a clone instance of Workbook , still writing in the template :(

Comment: @ulquiorra If you did it correctly there is zero possibility that it should be writing over the template. You created a  new workbook and used clone sheet http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#cloneSheet%28int%29 or any other cloning method on your template to create a new workbook instance with the template files?

Comment: @Javant . Thank you for your answer . i didn't clone sheet ( my excel file has many sheets). I just create a new instance of Workbook , then working with this one

Comment: @ulquiorra did it work or are you still working on it?

Comment: @Javant It didn't . I am still on it :/

Comment: Replace your call to `book.write(ByteArrayOutputStream)` with `book.write(FileOutputStream)` to have it write to the file!

Comment: @Gagravarr . Thanks ! see my updated code , it create the temp file correctly indeed,  but it still write on the template :(

Comment: Open the file in `PackageAccess.READ` mode if you don't want to change the original file!

Comment: @Gagravarr Hello , thank you for your suggestions but i already tried this solution and i can't write in cell if i use PackageAccess.READ

Comment: Make sure you're using a new enough copy of Apache POI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution which resolves my problem

It seems that whenever i call `close` method on a workbook , it will automatically save the file on hard disk as coded in the library

```
public void close() throws IOException {
        if (this.packageAccess == PackageAccess.READ) {
            logger.log(POILogger.WARN, 
                    "The close() method is intended to SAVE a package. This package is open in READ ONLY mode, use the revert() method instead !");
            revert();
            return;
        }
        if (this.contentTypeManager == null) {
            logger.log(POILogger.WARN,
                    "Unable to call close() on a package that hasn't been fully opened yet");
            return;
        }

        // Save the content
        ReentrantReadWriteLock l = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        try {
            l.writeLock().lock();
            if (this.originalPackagePath != null
                    && !"".equals(this.originalPackagePath.trim())) {
                File targetFile = new File(this.originalPackagePath);
                if (!targetFile.exists()
                        || !(this.originalPackagePath
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(targetFile.getAbsolutePath()))) {
                    // Case of a package created from scratch
                    save(targetFile);
                } else {
                    closeImpl();
                }
            } else if (this.output != null) {
                save(this.output);
                output.close();
            }
        } finally {
            l.writeLock().unlock();
        }

        // Clear
        this.contentTypeManager.clearAll();
    }
```

See http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Validating-office-files-without-saving-them-td5722653.html and https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59287

It happens only when a `File` or `OPCPackage`  is provided to the workbook.
The solution is to work with `InputStream` : `XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));` which will not overwrite the template as i wanted